# Same application acts both as client and server

Tags: networking, client

I want to build a networked chess game between two players.
when white makes a move it has to send its move to black
and vice versa. At the beginning I have to find some way to dynamically determine which
application waits for requests and being the server. If both applications wait I have a problem. I based my code on [this](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/)

How can I start from there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You do want a hybrid client/server design, but not using the sample code you are considering.  It is synchronous, using blocking socket calls that wait for a response before proceeding.

To avoid the situation where both client/server apps are blocked waiting to accept a connection from each other, you need to do non-blocking, asynchronous socket i/o.  For example, you could use the Java NIO library http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/